# How to count the occurrences of a character in a list of strings?

Tags: python

Indentation is messed up here but I want to count the number of times "." appears on the maze and make that the number of bits left but .count doesn't seem to be working. When I used the bitsLeft variable, it remained 0 rather than counting out the number of times "." appears in the array

```
level_1 = [
"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$",
"$!0......>0........#0>..$",
"$.0000.00000.0000000000.$",
"$...00.0#....0!00.0.000.$",
"$00.00.00000.0.00.0.000.$",
"$#0..........0..0.0.....$",
"$.0000.00000.00.0.0.000.$",
"$......0........0.0.0...$",
"$.000000.00000000...0.0.$",
"$.0......0...0...00.0.0.$",
"$...000000>0...0....0.0.$",
"$00.000000000000000.0.0.$",
"$...0.....0000!0........$",
"$.000.000.0>#0.0.00000.0$",
"$.....0.0.0..0.0.0..0..0$",
"$.00000.0.0..0.0.0..0.0.$",
"$.0>....0.0000.0.0..0.0.$",
"$.00000.0...P..0.0000.0.$",
"$....00.00000000.0....0.$",
"$000.00..........0.0000.$",
"$!0..00.00000000.0......$",
"$.0.000..........0.0000.$",
"$.0.0000.0000000.0.0>00.$",
"$........0#........0....$",
"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"
]

bitsLeft = level_1.count ('.')
```

Comment: Take a look at the `collections` module. It has a `Counter` class; [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

Comment: @kstullich not necessary in this case, if you simply want to count `.` then the builtin `str.count` will significantly faster

Comment: Your fundamental problem is that `level_1` is a *list* of strings. You want to count the number of times that `.` appears in each of those strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `sum` and a list comprehension that gets the count for each string, like so:

```
sum(s.count(".") for s in level_1)
```

Result:

```
265
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a ton

Comment: @randomname14 No problem, make sure to accept an answer by clicking the checkmark next to it if your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

[string.count()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) expects one string. You could use `''.join(level_1)` to concatenate the strings for the `str.count()` method:

```
bitsLeft = ''.join(level_1).count ('.')
```

Comment: `list.count()` is being called in his provided code.